# StaticPagedList together with a POST form: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a typical table, based on the `PagedList.StaticPagedList`.

My view model is as follows:

```
public class UpcomingOverviewViewModels
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public StaticPagedList<OverdueUpcomingInvoiceViewModel> OverduesPaged { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedInvoicesIds { get; set; }

    public UpcomingOverviewVideModels()
    {

    }
}
```

My view goes as follows beneath. Whole idea is that I have a form wrapping a table, and when I `POST`, I select a couple of records I can send.

The challenge is, that when I POST to my endpoint, `StartDebtCollectionCases`, I get the following error:

> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'PagedList.StaticPagedList`1[[Likvido.Models.Upcoming.OverdueUpcomingInvoiceViewModel, Likvido, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.]

**What I don't understand**: is that my viewmodel DO have a parameterless constructor. Yes, the StaticPagedList do not, but why is that being called at all?

**My view:**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("StartDebtCollectionCases", "Upcoming", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table class="table table-responsive-lg table-bordered table-striped table-sm mb-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Start inkassosag</th>
                    <th>
                        Faktura#
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Debitor
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.OverduesPaged.Count; i++)
                {


                    <tr>

                        <td>

                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OverduesPaged[i].InvoiceId)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OverduesPaged[i].Debtor)
                                <label>
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.OverduesPaged[i].IsSelected)
                                    Start case
                                </label>
                            }

                        </td>
                        <td>@Model.OverduesPaged[i].InvoiceId</td>
                        <td>@Model.OverduesPaged[i].Debtor.ToString()</td>

                    </tr>

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Start inkassosager" type="submit" />
    }
    <br /><br />
    Side @(Model.OverduesPaged.PageCount < Model.OverduesPaged.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.OverduesPaged.PageNumber) af @Model.OverduesPaged.PageCount. Totalt antal resultater:
    @Model.OverduesPaged.TotalItemCount stk

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.OverduesPaged, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))

</div>
```

Comment: The model binder has to create `StaticPagedList` in order to populate it with data durig nthe POST. All models being created need to have a parameterless constructor

Comment: @Nkosi Got it. I don't care about the paged list in the POST - what is the best way to "ignore it" here?

Comment: Well it looks like you use it as the model on the get. Use another model for the post that excludes that property type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I don't understand: is that my viewmodel DO have a parameterless constructor. Yes, the StaticPagedList do not, but why is that being called at all?

That's the wrong question. It doesn't matter why the constructor is being called.

Every property in the view-model **must** be of a type which has a parameterless constructor. That's just the way MVC works. There really is no point in arguing about it.

If you ignore the rule, you get the error message.

Just use `List<T>`, `Array<T>`, or create a new type which inherits the one you want which *does* have a parameterless constructor:

```
public class MyList : StaticPagedList<OverdueUpcomingInvoiceViewModel>
{
     public MyList() : base(new OverdueUpcomingInvoiceViewModel[] { }, 1, 1, 0)
     {
     }
}
```

i would use `List<OverdueUpcomingInvoiceViewModel>`